# Javascript error not returning the correct line number

Tags: javascript, ios, debugging

I'm currently debugging in safari (a hybrid iOS 6 app).  The line number for the error in a try catch is displaying the wrong line. The line number reported is pointing to the method not the line that errors.

For illustration, i'll provide an example

```
1. var myFunc = function(){
2.
3. try{
4. //do some work
5. var i = undefined;
6. }
7. catch(e){
8.     console.log(e.line);
9. }
10. //do some more work
11.
12. }
```

An error will be triggered on line 5, the variable undefined is undefined.  When the app runs the line error reported will be line 1.  So its pointing you to the function the error occurs in, not the actual line number.

Interestingly when I open the debugger and put a breakpoint on line 8 it begins printing the correct line which is line 5.  Even removing the breakpoint but keeping the debugger open will print the correct line. Once remote debugging is closed it resumes printing the method level line number.

This may be an iOS safari issue but its very strange.  Any ideas?